# Why does the implementation of std::to_string create a buffer 4 times the size of the type?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring

C++11 introduces `std::to_string`, so I took a look at one implementation: it calls `vsnprintf` internally.  Okay, but why does it always set the size parameter as 4 times the size of the type?

```
 inline string
 to_string(int __val)
 { return __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<string>(&std::vsnprintf, 4 * sizeof(int),
                                          "%d", __val); }

 inline string
 to_string(unsigned __val)
 { return __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<string>(&std::vsnprintf,
                                          4 * sizeof(unsigned),
                                          "%u", __val); }

 inline string
 to_string(long __val)
 { return __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<string>(&std::vsnprintf, 4 * sizeof(long),
                                          "%ld", __val); }
```

Comment: it'll create a buffer big enough to accommodate the string plus the trailing zero for all sizes of int, from 1 up.

Comment: Free review: they really should have used `sizeof __val` in my opinion.

Comment: @unwind not necessary, because to_string is  overloaded for type T.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The maximal number of binary digits of a N-decimal value is the ceil value of (N * log(10) / log(2)). A single decimal digit needs ceil(3.32) binary digits, That is 4.

For sizes of 8 bits it is:

```
Decimals = ceil(8 * Size / 3.32) = ceil(2.41 * Size).
```

For the sign (overhead and allocation) you get:

```
Decimals = 4 * Size.
```

Note: A conversion with snprintf of a single signed char needs 5 bytes (including the sign and the terminating zero). For values with a size greater than one byte, `Decimals = 4 * Size` provides a result, which is big enough.

Comment: Just for curiosity, how did you find this equation ?

Comment: @Garf365 this a changement of base, the number is encoded in base 2 (binary), and written in base 10.